# Nginx errors on some browser

Tags: nginx, server, configuration

I have some problems to call an API endpoint from my server.

I receive an error 500 and the page content says

```
The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable.
Please try again later.
```

But this problem occurs only on some browser/computer, it works normally on others
For example, I have this problem on Firefox and it works on Chrome
and one of my customer has the error on Chrome.

On the server, I have found this error log (`/nginx/localhost`):

```
94.xxx.xxx.xxx:- - - [05/Oct/2022:11:10:33 +0000] "POST /api/auth/login HTTP/3" 500 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" "-" "www.mydomain.com"
```

This server is hosted on a Jelastic platform and it's used as a load balancer to redirect traffic on other servers.

My nginx config file is (I have masked IPs and domain) :

```
######## HTTP SECTION PROTOTYPE ########

http {
    server_tokens off ;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        set_real_ip_from  192.xxx.xxx.xxx/16;
        set_real_ip_from  10.xxx.xxx.xxx/8;
        set_real_ip_from  172.xxx.xxx.xxx/16;
        real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
        real_ip_recursive on;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr:$http_x_remote_port - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                      '"$host" sn="$server_name" '
                      'rt=$request_time '
                      'ua="$upstream_addr" us="$upstream_status" '
                      'ut="$upstream_response_time" ul="$upstream_response_length" '
                      'cs=$upstream_cache_status' ;

        client_header_timeout 10m;
        client_body_timeout 10m;
        send_timeout 10m;
        client_max_body_size 100m;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;

        connection_pool_size 256;
        client_header_buffer_size 1k;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 32k; # 8k to 32k
        request_pool_size 4k;
  
        #Allow large token
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_buffers 4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        #proxy_buffering off;

#        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1100;
        gzip_buffers 4 8k;
        gzip_types text/plain;

        output_buffers 1 32k;
        postpone_output 1460;

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;

        keepalive_timeout 75 20;

        ignore_invalid_headers on;

    ### UPSTREAMS LIST FOLLOWS HERE ###
        #upstream nodes{ server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX; server 127.0.0.1:8001 backup # UPSTREAMPROTO # This is upstream prototype line, do not remove this! }
#This config is auto-generated. DO NOT modify the weight property. If changing the rest of settings, please, remember that you are doing this at your own risk.
upstream common {     check interval=30000 rise=2 fall=5 timeout=10000 default_down=false type=http; check_http_send "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\r\n\r\n";  keepalive 100;  server mydomain.jcloud-ver-jpe.ik-server.com  weight=100 ; } ### UPSTREAMPROTO for common ###


        #GFADMIN

        server {
                listen *:80;
                listen [::]:80;
                server_name  _;

                access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access_log main;
                error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log info;

                proxy_temp_path /var/nginx/tmp/;
                proxy_connect_timeout 5s;

                error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

                proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Remote-Port $http_x_remote_port;
                proxy_set_header X-URI $request_uri;
                proxy_set_header X-ARGS $args;
                proxy_set_header Refer $http_refer;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                if ($http_x_remote_port = '' ) {
                    set $http_x_remote_port $remote_port;
                }
      
                location = /50x.html {
                        root   html;
                }

                location / {
                        proxy_pass http://common;
                }

        
                #USERLOCATIONS
        }

#        server {
#                listen *:8001;
#                server_name  backup.local;
#
#           location / {
#                        proxy_pass http://default_upstream;
#                        add_header Set-Cookie "SRVGROUP=$group; path=/; HttpOnly";
#                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
#                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
#                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#                        proxy_set_header X-Host $http_host;
#                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
#                        proxy_set_header X-URI $request_uri;
#                        proxy_set_header X-ARGS $args;
#                        proxy_set_header Refer $http_refer;
#                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
#                        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
#                }
#        }

 include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}

######## TCP SECTION PROTOTYPE ########
```

It's the first time I look at nginx config file, any advice or idea are welcome :)

Comment: Your nginx conf file looks ok. Most likely, the error is happening on an upstream which has browser specific handling. The log message you've pasted is a 304 redirect response from an upstream.

Comment: Oups have copied the wrong line. Here is the error log (also updated in the question) : `94.xxx.xxx.xxx:- - - [05/Oct/2022:11:10:33 +0000] "POST /api/auth/login HTTP/3" 500 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0" "-" "www.mydomain.com"`